# How to set a cell value depeinding on a specefic cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate the excel sheet by checking the value of a specific cell, and setting multiple columns with a value.

For example if `A1` cell is "2" then I would like all the cells from `B2:D54` to be the value equal to 0. I have a code written but it looks like it is wrong.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    //this selects the cell C3 and checks if the value if is 0619
    If Range("C3")="0619"
        Dim example As Range
        Set example =Range("E3:AE53")
        example.Value = 0
    End if
End Sub
```

---

**Edit** - Added `Then`, but still not working.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    //this selects the cell C3 and checks if the value if is 0619
    If Range("C3")="0619" Then
        Dim example As Range
        Set example =Range("E3:AE53")
        example.Value = 0
    End if
End Sub
```

Comment: You've missed `THEN` at the end of the `If Range(...` line.  You may want to add `Application.EnableEvents=False` at the start of the procedure and `Application.EnableEvents=True` at the end as you're adding 1377 values to the sheet and the Change event will fire for each one.

Comment: I did add THEN but it still doesnot work

Comment: Is `C3` formatted as text?  If not it will read the cell as 619 which doesn't match your condition.

Comment: If C3 is a number formated as `0000` (leading zero) then use `If Range("C3").Text ="0619" Then`. Also `Application.EnableEvents=False` and `Application.EnableEvents=True` as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Make sure your columns are wide enough if you use `Text` as @Jeeped suggests - too narrow and it will see `#` instead.  Maybe use `If Format(Range("C4"), "0000") = "0619" Then`, but might as well just check for `619` in that case.

Comment: btw, if you have made repeated attempts without disabling events then it is possible that your event handling is hooped. Try running `Application.EnableEvents=True` from the VBE's Immediate window.

Answer (score 1):

- You are missing `Then` in the line with `If`
- Comments in VBA are started with `'`, not `//` so this will not parse correctly.
- `If Range("C3")="0619"` Bear in mind Excel will remove leading zeros from numbers. Only have leading zeros if you will be formatting the value as text.
- Edit: `If Range("C3").Value` better than `If Range("C3")`

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   'this selects the cell C3 and checks if the value if is 0619
    If Range("C3").Value = "0619" Then
        Dim example As Range
        Set example = Range("E3:AE53")
        example.Value = 0

    End If
'
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- only perform the work if C3 is changed.
- if C3 is a number formatted as 0000 (leading zero) then use `If Range("C3").Text ="0619" Then`
- as mentioned in comments, disable events or your routine will try to run on top of itself when you change the values in the cells.
- event driven sub procedures should have error control

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    if not intersect(target, range("C3")) is nothing then
        on error goto safe_exit
        application.enableevents = false
        select case range("C3").text
            case "0619"
                Range("E3:AE53") = 0
            case else
                'do nothing
        end select
    End if
safe_exit:
    application.enableevents = true
End Sub
```

I've changed your criteria check to a Select Case statement to make it easier to accommodate additional conditions.